# JQuery not working in view model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have an MVC project that uses some JQuery that works fine on my Create page. I am trying to create a view using a View Model but when I do the JQuery doesn't work. Any idea why it wouldn't be working? I'm using JQuery 2.1.1 . I'm guessing there is a reference I'm missing but I can't figure out where. The datepicker isn't working

_Layout (Condensed)

```
<html>
   <head>
       @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

       <!--Jquery -->
       <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
       <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

   </head>
   <body>

   </body>

   <!--Custom javascript-->
   <script src="~/Scripts/Custom/custom.js"></script>
</html>
```

Both views have

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Model View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Approved_Date, new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

ViewModel

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.vm.Approved_Date, new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //calendar
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            $(this).valid();
        }
    });
});
```

Controller for VM

```
public ActionResult VMPage()
{
    MEOViewModel vm = new MEOViewModel();

    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: Don't understand what is the problem. Is it that the date picker not appearing or the valid() function is not working as expected?

Comment: Same old question every time: Is your jQuery code wrapped in a *document ready* event? :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will take that as a *yes*. Answer deleted :)

Comment: Yeah it is, my mistake for not showing that. I updated the code in the question

Comment: Works fine standalone: http://jsfiddle.net/7w3NA/ can you show your HTML output (saved from browser)? What does your `"~/bundles/jquery"` bundle look like?

Comment: Can you also show your controller method as `model.vm.anything` is a bit unusual? What you have labelled as `ViewModel` looks like part of another view (or partial view).

Comment: I deleted the page and generated a new one. It seems to be working now. No idea why it wasn't before like you said it should have been. If I ever come across it again or figure out what I was doing wrong I'll post my answer. Thanks again for all the help